# How to extract all the values and decimal point values from an image

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing a problem while extracting text from an image.

The problem is, while extracting the .jpg image, all the datas are able to do except some specific fractional values which contains digit like **172641** %.

Actually in the image the value is **17.2641** but after extraction, particular decimal point is not reading and getting result as 172641.

Please help me to get all the values including decimal point.

im using below code :

```
try 
{
    IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
    while (files.MoveNext())
    {
        string ls_Outputpath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.LastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\Output\\Result_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".txt";
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(files.Current));
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(files.Current).Replace(fileExtension, string.Empty).Trim();
        string strImageTextFileName = string.Empty;
        if (fileExtension == ".jpg" || fileExtension == ".JPG" || fileExtension == ".Jpeg")
        {
            gs_Filename = fileName;
            try
            {
                MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
                md.Create(Convert.ToString(files.Current));
                try
                {
                    md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log(ex.Message.ToString(), gsLogFileName);
                }
                MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
                FileStream createFile =
                new FileStream(fileName + ".txt", FileMode.CreateNew);
                strImageTextFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(createFile);
                writeFile.Write(image.Layout.Text);
                writeFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log("Exception in Extracting text from Image :" + ex.Message.ToString(), gsLogFileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Sounds like an OCR software issue not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying another OCR engine, like [Tesseract](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract).
Their sample was able to do that:

[image]

Comment: Do we need to add any other dll. If yes, please share me the path to get it.

Comment: Yes, tesseract engine dll is required, obviously. Please go to linked above github repostory and eximine tesseract/Samples/Tesseract.ConsoleDemo project. You can donwload source code and build it, all dependencies are there.

Comment: i tried with tessnet. Getting error like, Could not load file or assembly 'tessnet2_64, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1550524b5ba07e29' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows, consider using the new Microsoft OCR component. It works very well. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Ocr/

Comment: If on Windows 10, OCR is system API
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.ocr.aspx